# How to prepend the output of a command if it updates lines instead of adding new ones?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I wanted to prepend the output (progress) of `rclone` with custom text. After some googling I've come up with this solution:

```
rclone sync "$SOURCE" "$DESTINATION" | while read line; do echo "   $line"; done
```

But actually rclone (with --progress) grabs some lines at start and then just updates them during its execution. But using `while` I end up with constant adding new lines instead of  updating old ones. Does anybody know how to fix it ?

Default `rclone --progress output`, it is updated every second:

```
Transferred:             0 / 0 Bytes, -, 0 Bytes/s, ETA -
Checks:                97 / 97, 100%
Elapsed time:         0.0s
```

Desired output:

```
[My text] Transferred:             0 / 0 Bytes, -, 0 Bytes/s, ETA -
[My text] Checks:                97 / 97, 100%
[My text] Elapsed time:         0.0s
```

Actual result with `while`, it does NOT update, it adds instead:

```
[My text] Transferred:             0 / 0 Bytes, -, 0 Bytes/s, ETA -
[My text] Checks:                97 / 97, 100%
[My text] Elapsed time:         0.0s
[My text] Transferred:             0 / 0 Bytes, -, 0 Bytes/s, ETA -
[My text] Checks:                97 / 97, 100%
[My text] Elapsed time:         0.0s
[My text] Transferred:             0 / 0 Bytes, -, 0 Bytes/s, ETA -
[My text] Checks:                97 / 97, 100%
[My text] Elapsed time:         0.0s
[My text] Transferred:             0 / 0 Bytes, -, 0 Bytes/s, ETA -
[My text] Checks:                97 / 97, 100%
[My text] Elapsed time:         0.0s
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question. If what you want to do is constantly update the same line, you can use something like:

```
rclone sync "$SOURCE" "$DESTINATION" | while read line; do echo -en "   \r$line"; done
```

> -n will stop echo to print the trailing newline
>
> -e will instruct echo to evaluate backslash sequences

Comment: I've supplemented description with an example

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to control this type of updating, mainly because not all programs send the full update data and always in the same position. In this particular case, `rclone` seems to send the three full data lines every second, so we have to modify them AND also redraw in the same position erasing the old ones, because if the newer are shorter than the older they will mix on the screen. For me, the easiest way is using the `clear` command and show only the data lines in the upper left corner each redrawing:

```
rclone sync "$SOURCE" "$DESTINATION" | while read line; do if echo "$line" | grep -q  "Transferred"; then clear; fi ; echo "   $line"; done
```

If we want more control, we can use ANSI escape cursor position codes to precisely put each specific output line in some predefined screen position, using `grep` to determine which line is currently being printed. Or we could use `read A B C... <<<$line` to extract single data fields from each line and wholly reorganize the output as we want. Of course, there exists more efficient ways of doing this, maybe with `awk`, etc. Caveat: Even if `rclone` unbuffer its output, could be necessary to do that for stdin/stdout on the `while` command to guarantee a timely redrawing - I didn't make any tests.

I recommend grouping the commands in a script, say `rclone.format.sh`, to simplify the calling and debugging: `rclone sync "src" "dst" | ./rclone.format`

```
#!/bin/bash
# formatting rclone progress output
# use: rclone [options] | rclone.format.sh
#--------------------
TXTPFIX="my customized progress text"

while read LINE ; do
  if echo "$LINE" | grep -iq transferred ; then
    #-- erase screen on first line detected
    clear
  fi
  #-- send modified line
  echo "$TXTPFIX $LINE"
done
#-- end --#
```

Don't forget `chmod u+x rclone.format.sh` to permit simple script execution.